# OnOptionItemSelected is not using proper values

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have got kind of a wierd problem - my `app` is built from `fragments`. The main idea is that user gets list of `days` with some plans to do. User can add a day, the end of the adding process should show again day list (with menu item to add another day).

Flow is as follows:

1. User opens day list (day number is set to dayList.size())
2. User click on menu item in order to add new day
3. fragment.replace is being called with dayList.size() as a bundle
4. user is entering proper values and is going back to dayList using fragment.replace
5. dayList is being reloaded (another api call etc)
6. User click on menu item in order to add new day
7. **fragment.replace is being called with dayList.size() as a bundle - here is where problem starts - dayList.size() is not actual size of a list (which should be bigger then it is in point 3) but it is exacly same value which it was in point 3**

dayList fragment is :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    initializeData(view);
}

public void initializeData(final View view){
    Call<List<Days>> call = apiService.getDays();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Days>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Days>> call, Response<List<Days>> response) {
            dayRequests = response.body();
            Log.d("x","SETTING DAYS COUNT TO: "+ dayRequests.size());
            daysCount = dayRequests.size();
            setupDayRecycler(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Days>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_addday,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_addplan);
    if (item !=null)
        item.setVisible(false);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_addday) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Log.e("xxx", "DAYS COUNT IN MENU CLICK : " + daysCount);
        bundle.putInt("addday", daysCount+1);
        Fragment fragment = AddDayFragment.newInstance();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, "adbck");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

my `AddDayFragment` is ending like:

```
Fragment fragment = MyDaysFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment,"adback");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

log output is :

```
03-14 08:19:01.953 19380-19380/com.example E/x: SETTING DAYS COUNT TO: 5
03-14 08:19:06.299 19380-19380/com.example E/xxx: DAYS COUNT IN MENU CLICK : 5
03-14 08:19:11.029 19380-19380/com.example E/x: SETTING DAYS COUNT TO: 6
03-14 08:19:14.466 19380-19380/com.example E/xxx: DAYS COUNT IN MENU CLICK : 5
```

It looks like `onOptionsItemSelected` method is not geting proper values, could anyone give me a hint why?

Comment: is this your complete code? `onCreateOptionsMenu` method is missing

Comment: @AwaisMajeed whole class is quite big so I pasted only methods I thought will matter. `onCreateOptionsMenu` is in edited question. My apologies.

Comment: @Mithrand1r Can you please paste whole class, because this is game of references you know!